# JSON response is not ordering properly according to SQL query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I'm having a problem with my JSON array. On first load, the order is not as it should be (as defined in the SQL query).

So the main problem is, on page load, i.e. when the SQL query is called with lastPoll=null - the results are not sorted by time1 DESC, yet they are sorted by the s.id ASC. When I enter a new result, and then run the query with the lastPoll set in the query, then the latest is added to the top, as it should be.

Weird part is - if I view the raw JSON response at push.php with the correct params in the URL, the response is correct and in the correct order. So, the problem must lie in the parsing?

Here is the SQL Query:

```
$getActivityUpdates1 = mysql_query("
    SELECT
        s.id, u.name, u.profilePic, s.userid,  s.content, s.time1, s.imageKey
    FROM
        status_updates s 
    INNER JOIN
        users1 u ON u.id = s.userid 
    WHERE
        competitionId = '$competitionId' AND s.time1 > '$lastPoll'
    ORDER BY s.time1 DESC");

$results = array('items' => array());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getActivityUpdates1)) 
{
    $results['items'][] = array(
    'statusid' => $row['id'],
    'name' => $row['name'], 
    'profilePic' => $row['profilePic'],
    'content' => $row['content'],
    'time1' => $row['time1'],
    'imageKey' => $row['imageKey'],
    );
}

die(json_encode($results));
?>
```

Here is the Javascript where I re-run the query.

```
var lastPoll = null;     
function loadActivity(onDone) {

    var competitionId = $("body").attr("data-competitionId");
    console.log(lastPoll);

    if (lastPoll == null) { // We have never polled, we want to pull everything and populate  the list.
        url = "push.php?competitionId=" + competitionId + "&lastPoll=1999-01-01 22:00:00"; 
    } else { // We have polled once, send the date and time of that last poll to capture only new entries.
        url = "push.php?competitionId=" + competitionId + "&lastPoll=" + lastPoll;   
    }

    $.get(url, function(data) {
        jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);

        var spot = $("#activityspot");
        var template = spot.find(".template");

        for (var j = 0; j < jsonData.items.length; j++) {
            var entryData = jsonData.items[j];
            var entry = template.clone();
            entry.removeClass("template");

            entry.find(".message").text(entryData.statusid);
            spot.prepend(entry);
        }

        if (onDone) {
            onDone();
        }

        lastPoll = js_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss();

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are producing your results in reverse time order, but then also adding them to the page in reverse order (with `.prepend`).  The net result is that the two reversals cancel each other out such that each batch of results is added to the top of the list in *ascending* time order.

If the intent is to actually have them displayed in reverse order just get rid of the `DESC` qualifier from the query and rely on the `.prepend` call to add each successive entry to the top of the page.

Comment: Can I ask one more question Alnitak? Regarding building the templates for each activity - can I add more content from the JSON to these two lines? For example, if I want to also put the image in there, and give that image a specific class, how would I get all of that into the one "entry"?

entry.find(".message").text(entryData.statusid);
spot.prepend(entry);